# React hook form field array validation not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have a field array where I have an input field for which I have set some validation rules like `required` and `minLength`.
I would like to when a new field is appended to have immediate validation on this fields. But, that is not happening, even when I append empty fields, errors stay undefined for those input fields:

```
function App() {
  const useFormMethods = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      test: [{ firstName: "Bill", lastName: "Luo" }]
    },
    mode: "onChange"
  });
  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
    control: useFormMethods.control,
    name: "test",
    rules: {
      minLength: 4
    }
  });

  const onSubmit = (data) => console.log("data", data);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...useFormMethods}>
      <form onSubmit={useFormMethods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <h1>Field Array </h1>
        <span className="counter">Render Count: {renderCount}</span>
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <li key={item.id}>
                <FormControlledInput name={`test.${index}.firstName`} />
                <FormControlledInput name={`test.${index}.lastName`} />
                <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
                  Delete
                </button>
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
        <section>
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={() => {
              append({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
            }}
          >
            append
          </button>
        </section>

        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

This is the controlled input that needs validation:

```
export const FormControlledInput = ({ name }) => {
  const {
    control,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext();

  const { field, fieldState } = useController({
    name,
    control,
    rules: { required: true }
  });

  console.log(`fieldState error: `, fieldState.error);
  console.log(`formState errors: `, errors);

  return <input onChange={field.onChange} value={field.value} />;
};
```

You can check the working codesandbox example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-rules-forked-cl9dgi?file=/src/index.js).
What do I need to do to have it validate on each change?

Answer (score 0):

The `append` method you're using to add the field to the array is asynchronous, as is the `trigger` method to perform the validation, so there's a race condition that is causing the validation to be triggered before the field is registered with the form. You can just `await` that function result before triggering a revalidate when an array field is added.

```
          <button
            type="button"
            onClick={async () => {
              await append({ firstName: "", lastName: "" });
              useFormMethods.trigger();
            }}
          >
            append
          </button>
```

I forked your CSB [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-rules-forked-z300dk?file=/src/index.js:1393-1629). I also added a `useEffect` hook that will trigger validation when the component is mounted.